# Weird Decoded JavaScript Code

Tags: javascript

In my journey to learn JavaScript I encountered today this strange code in a script that I'm trying to read its code and understanding.

```
var j =["\\1A\\W\\1g","\\X\\S\\1p\\M","\\I\\G\\x\\H\\x\\H\\V\\I\\M","\\s\\W\\L\\1o\\z","\\W\\z\\W\\H","\\1v\\S\\1p\\1B\\T\\z\\1C\\G\\x\\I\\M\\G\\H\\V"];
```

I tried to console log the value of the j variable like this.

```
console.log(j[1] + '' + j[2] + '' + j[3] + '' + j[4] + '' + j[5] + '' + j[6]);
```

but unfortunately the console gave me an error which is "undefined". So is there any one can help me figure out how I can read this code.

Comment: Array's are zero-based, so you would want to start with `0`. Something like this: `console.log(j[0] + '' + j[1] + '' + j[2] + '' + j[3] + '' + j[4] + '' + j[5]);`

Comment: This looks like obfuscation javascript. It is an attempt to prevent people from copy-pasting code as their own by hiding what it does.

Comment: @JackPattishall Even if you start with zero it didn't work

Comment: @rlb.usa Since JavaScript is client side there is no way to hide your codes. So there should be a way that make you able to read this code.

Comment: The string itself is kind of useless without the function that deobfuscates it. It would help if you looked for the function that converts `j` to readable code, then add a `console.log()` where it would normally return / execute the result.

Comment: @Abdelghafour It does exist. See here : http://javascriptobfuscator.com/ This is one of many that exist.

Comment: @rlb.usa but you can read the codes in the array with console. Try this console.log("\x70\x75\x73\x68");

Comment: @railgun The code is completely incomprehensible, Take a look http://jsfiddle.net/3vam4t7a/

Comment: @Abdelghafour Yes, this is true. Obfuscators cannot truly hide code if someone wants to get it. They are only a speed bump. But they will deter anyone who is not determined enough. There are other questions on this site that talk about it better than I can as a single comment.

Comment: @Abdelghafour You need to "catch" the returned code and log it into the browser *before* it gets evaluated.

Comment: @railgun The question is how I can do that ? because I still a nob and I have no Idea about what you said now so If you can give me a tutorial or something like that I will appreciate that. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned in the comments, this is JavaScript obfuscation. From the looks of it, it's attempting to read values from a page (via jQuery). Here's a quick breakdown:

In the fiddle you linked with the script, you'll find an eval is called on `minified` or `packed` code. There are two parts two it - the script that executes and the argument passed. When you prettify the script, it looks like this:

```
function(d, e, a, c, b, f) {
    b = function(a) {
        return (a < e ? "" : b(parseInt(a / e))) + (35 < (a %= e) ? String.fromCharCode(a + 29) : a.toString(36))
    };

    if (!"".replace(/^/, String)) {
        for (; a--;) f[b(a)] = c[a] || b(a);
        c = [function(a) {
            return f[a]
        }];
        b = function() {
            return "\\w+"
        };
        a = 1
    }

    for (; a--;) c[a] && (d = d.replace(new RegExp("\\b" + b(a) + "\\b", "g"), c[a]));

    return d
}
```

The long string of code (assigned to the variable J) is returned and then eval'd. This returns another array of values ([found here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/9a176e2f971458988c79/raw/dc7d154645526187bbb0f72a2864b421c2179115/gistfile1.js)) a Crypto function, and other self-executing functions. This is what the crypto function looks like:

```
var CryptoJS = CryptoJS || function(e, f) {
    var g = {},
        _0xda47x5 = g[_0x52e0[0]] = {},
        _0xda47x6 = function() {},
        _0xda47x7 = _0xda47x5[_0x52e0[1]] = {
            extend: function(a) {
                _0xda47x6[_0x52e0[2]] = this;
                var b = new _0xda47x6;
                a && b[_0x52e0[3]](a);
                b[_0x52e0[5]](_0x52e0[4]) || (b[_0x52e0[4]] = function() {
                    b[_0x52e0[7]][_0x52e0[4]][_0x52e0[6]](this, arguments)
                });
                b[_0x52e0[4]][_0x52e0[2]] = b;
                b[_0x52e0[7]] = this;
                return b
            },
            create: function() {
                var a = this[_0x52e0[8]]();
                a[_0x52e0[4]][_0x52e0[6]](a, arguments);
                return a
            },
            init: function() {},
            mixIn: function(a) {
                for (var b in a) {
                    a[_0x52e0[5]](b) && (this[b] = a[b])
                };
                a[_0x52e0[5]](_0x52e0[9]) && (this[_0x52e0[9]] = a[_0x52e0[9]])
            },
            clone: function() {
                return this[_0x52e0[4]][_0x52e0[2]][_0x52e0[8]](this)
            }
        },
        _0xda47x8 = _0xda47x5[_0x52e0[10]] = _0xda47x7[_0x52e0[8]]({
            init: function(a, b) {
                a = this[_0x52e0[11]] = a || [];
                this[_0x52e0[12]] = b != f ? b : 4 * a[_0x52e0[13]]
            },
            toString: function(a) {
                return (a || _0xda47xa)[_0x52e0[14]](this)
            },
            concat: function(a) {
                var b = this[_0x52e0[11]],
                    _0xda47x10 = a[_0x52e0[11]],
                    _0xda47x11 = this[_0x52e0[12]];
                a = a[_0x52e0[12]];
                this[_0x52e0[15]]();
                if (_0xda47x11 % 4) {
                    for (var c = 0; c < a; c++) {
                        b[_0xda47x11 + c >>> 2] |= (_0xda47x10[c >>> 2] >>> 24 - 8 * (c % 4) & 255) << 24 - 8 * ((_0xda47x11 + c) % 4)
                    }
                } else {
                    if (65535 < _0xda47x10[_0x52e0[13]]) {
                        for (c = 0; c < a; c += 4) {
                            b[_0xda47x11 + c >>> 2] = _0xda47x10[c >>> 2]
                        }
                    } else {
                        b[_0x52e0[16]][_0x52e0[6]](b, _0xda47x10)
                    }
                };
                this[_0x52e0[12]] += a;
                return this
            },
            clamp: function() {
                var a = this[_0x52e0[11]],
                    _0xda47xf = this[_0x52e0[12]];
                a[_0xda47xf >>> 2] &= 4294967295 << 32 - 8 * (_0xda47xf % 4);
                a[_0x52e0[13]] = e[_0x52e0[17]](_0xda47xf / 4)
            },
            clone: function() {
                var a = _0xda47x7[_0x52e0[19]][_0x52e0[18]](this);
                a[_0x52e0[11]] = this[_0x52e0[11]][_0x52e0[20]](0);
                return a
            },
            random: function(a) {
                for (var b = [], _0xda47x10 = 0; _0xda47x10 < a; _0xda47x10 += 4) {
                    b[_0x52e0[16]](4294967296 * e[_0x52e0[21]]() | 0)
                };
                return new _0xda47x8[_0x52e0[4]](b, a)
            }
        }),
        _0xda47x9 = g[_0x52e0[22]] = {},
        _0xda47xa = _0xda47x9[_0x52e0[23]] = {
            stringify: function(a) {
                var b = a[_0x52e0[11]];
                a = a[_0x52e0[12]];
                for (var c = [], _0xda47x11 = 0; _0xda47x11 < a; _0xda47x11++) {
                    var d = b[_0xda47x11 >>> 2] >>> 24 - 8 * (_0xda47x11 % 4) & 255;
                    c[_0x52e0[16]]((d >>> 4).toString(16));
                    c[_0x52e0[16]]((d & 15).toString(16))
                };
                return c[_0x52e0[25]](_0x52e0[24])
            },
            parse: function(a) {
                for (var b = a[_0x52e0[13]], _0xda47x10 = [], _0xda47x11 = 0; _0xda47x11 < b; _0xda47x11 += 2) {
                    _0xda47x10[_0xda47x11 >>> 3] |= parseInt(a[_0x52e0[26]](_0xda47x11, 2), 16) << 24 - 4 * (_0xda47x11 % 8)
                };
                return new _0xda47x8[_0x52e0[4]](_0xda47x10, b / 2)
            }
        },
        _0xda47xb = _0xda47x9[_0x52e0[27]] = {
            stringify: function(a) {
                var b = a[_0x52e0[11]];
                a = a[_0x52e0[12]];
                for (var c = [], _0xda47x11 = 0; _0xda47x11 < a; _0xda47x11++) {
                    c[_0x52e0[16]](String[_0x52e0[28]](b[_0xda47x11 >>> 2] >>> 24 - 8 * (_0xda47x11 % 4) & 255))
                };
                return c[_0x52e0[25]](_0x52e0[24])
            },
            parse: function(a) {
                for (var b = a[_0x52e0[13]], _0xda47x10 = [], _0xda47x11 = 0; _0xda47x11 < b; _0xda47x11++) {
                    _0xda47x10[_0xda47x11 >>> 2] |= (a[_0x52e0[29]](_0xda47x11) & 255) << 24 - 8 * (_0xda47x11 % 4)
                };
                return new _0xda47x8[_0x52e0[4]](_0xda47x10, b)
            }
        },
        _0xda47xc = _0xda47x9[_0x52e0[30]] = {
            stringify: function(a) {
                try {
                    return decodeURIComponent(escape(_0xda47xb[_0x52e0[14]](a)))
                } catch (c) {
                    throw Error(_0x52e0[31]);
                }
            },
            parse: function(a) {
                return _0xda47xb[_0x52e0[32]](unescape(encodeURIComponent(a)))
            }
        },
        _0xda47xd = _0xda47x5[_0x52e0[33]] = _0xda47x7[_0x52e0[8]]({
            reset: function() {
                this[_0x52e0[34]] = new _0xda47x8[_0x52e0[4]];
                this[_0x52e0[35]] = 0
            },
            _append: function(a) {
                _0x52e0[36] == typeof a && (a = _0xda47xc[_0x52e0[32]](a));
                this[_0x52e0[34]][_0x52e0[37]](a);
                this[_0x52e0[35]] += a[_0x52e0[12]]
            },
            _process: function(a) {
                var b = this[_0x52e0[34]],
                    _0xda47x10 = b[_0x52e0[11]],
                    _0xda47x11 = b[_0x52e0[12]],
                    _0xda47x12 = this[_0x52e0[38]],
                    _0xda47xb = _0xda47x11 / (4 * _0xda47x12),
                    _0xda47xb = a ? e[_0x52e0[17]](_0xda47xb) : e[_0x52e0[40]]((_0xda47xb | 0) - this[_0x52e0[39]], 0);
                a = _0xda47xb * _0xda47x12;
                _0xda47x11 = e[_0x52e0[41]](4 * a, _0xda47x11);
                if (a) {
                    for (var c = 0; c < a; c += _0xda47x12) {
                        this._doProcessBlock(_0xda47x10, c)
                    };
                    c = _0xda47x10[_0x52e0[42]](0, a);
                    b[_0x52e0[12]] -= _0xda47x11
                };
                return new _0xda47x8[_0x52e0[4]](c, _0xda47x11)
            },
            clone: function() {
                var a = _0xda47x7[_0x52e0[19]][_0x52e0[18]](this);
                a[_0x52e0[34]] = this[_0x52e0[34]][_0x52e0[19]]();
                return a
            },
            _minBufferSize: 0
        });
    _0xda47x5[_0x52e0[43]] = _0xda47xd[_0x52e0[8]]({
        cfg: _0xda47x7[_0x52e0[8]](),
        init: function(a) {
            this[_0x52e0[44]] = this[_0x52e0[44]][_0x52e0[8]](a);
            this[_0x52e0[45]]()
        },
        reset: function() {
            _0xda47xd[_0x52e0[45]][_0x52e0[18]](this);
            this._doReset()
        },
        update: function(a) {
            this._append(a);
            this._process();
            return this
        },
        finalize: function(a) {
            a && this._append(a);
            return this._doFinalize()
        },
        blockSize: 16,
        _createHelper: function(c) {
            return function(a, b) {
                return (new c[_0x52e0[4]](b))[_0x52e0[46]](a)
            }
        },
        _createHmacHelper: function(c) {
            return function(a, b) {
                return (new h[_0x52e0[47]][_0x52e0[4]](c, b))[_0x52e0[46]](a)
            }
        }
    });
    var h = g[_0x52e0[48]] = {};
    return g
}(Math);
```

I won't paste the other self-executing functions, but if you're interested - they can be found here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/73b41a89f073653ee405

Some of the more interesting variable names are:

```
var code_text1 = $(_0x52e0[111])[_0x52e0[110]]();
var decrypted = CryptoJS[_0x52e0[106]][_0x52e0[71]](code_text1, _0x52e0[112]);
var plaintext2 = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS[_0x52e0[22]].Utf8);
var code_text2 = plaintext2[_0x52e0[113]](/[^[\]]+(?=])/g);
var secretBlog = code_text2[0];
var urlBlog = code_text2[1];
```

The eval itself breaks because `code_text` is attempting to set the value when it executes `$(_0x52e0[111])[_0x52e0[110]]();`, which - deobfucscated, is `$('.buyer')['text']()`

My guess - and purely my guess because it depends on WHERE this code would be executed, is that this is injected into an e-commerce site, which reads a value (based on a `buyer` text), and sends (or redirects) to a (secret) blog or another URL.

Anyway, hope this helps and have fun learning JS!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should first beautify the code. It really is hard to see where to go if the code is a mess. The first step is to make it prettier (I use [jsbeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org)).

From there you'll see code similar to this:

```
eval(function(d, e, a, c, b, f) { ... }(...))
```

Because there is no complex obfuscation involved, we can simply replace `eval` with a variable statement.

```
var x = (function(d, e, a, c, b, f) { ... }(...))
```

Here we are basically telling the variable "x" to equal the returned code from the function. Next, `console.log()` the value of `x` like so.

```
console.log(x);
```

You'll notice that the code is a bit more readable now, progress! If you look through the output code, you'll notice that it follows a similar pattern of encoded characters. We can deobfuscate this code by entering it into jsbeautifier's simple textarea with "Unescape Printable Chars" checked.

[image: Deobfuscated code]

From here, you'll notice yet another `eval` statement at the bottom of the rendered code. I won't go down another level, but hopefully this post gives you the basics of deobfuscation. To continue deobfuscation, you'd simply remove the if statement and change eval to another variable declaration and `console.log()` that return.

As you go further into deobfuscation, you will be able to understand the source more.

The JavaScript obfuscator [CryptoJS](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/downloads/detail?name=CryptoJS%20v3.1.2.zip&can=2&q=) is open-source if you want to check out its source code.

Good luck!